# Run code on UI thread

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous

I need to submit code to be run in a thread that does message pumping, **without** defining several custom messages.
Something like the Java `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (NOTE: i already have an utility that allows a lambda to be callbackable)

I have already tried `::SendMessageCallback & SendAsyncProc`, but the callback is invoked by the same sender thread when it invokes `::GetMessage` (that is a requirement for that api...)

ATM my alternative is to define a custom message (ie. WM_USER_EXECUTE) to which pass the callback, but this require all the targets to be prepared to receive that message!
I would prefer a more generic way.

Comment: @Marting i'm investigating, thanks for the moment, i didn't know that api

Comment: @Martin Argh! it doesent work.. After the APC has been queued, nothing happens until the receiver thread enters an altertable state (es. by calling SleepEx with bAlertable TRUE)
Apparently the internals of ::GetMessage does not leave the thread in such state :(

Comment: add `SleepEx(0, TRUE);` in message loop then.

Comment: @Abyx - something else is going on.  IIRC, GetMessage() API does allow the processing of queued APC's.

Comment: @MartinJames, I mean something like `while(GetMessage(..)) { DispatchMessage(..); SleepEx(0, TRUE); }`

Comment: Oh shit - GetMessage() does not handle queued APC's - I was wrong above :(

Comment: @Abyx - would still require a Windows message to make the GetMessage() return and check for APC's :(

Comment: The only way round this that occurs now is to replace the GetMessage() call with MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() call.

Comment: @MartinJames, yep. that's why there is `PeekMessage`.

Comment: @Abyx - does not block.  Results in polling loop :(

Comment: I want to avoid modifying the routine on target threads (if i were forced instead of inserting SleepEx in the loop i would prefer make them handling a special message as i proposed before)
My best bet at the moment is to use SetWindowsHoowEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found a way to obtain what i need, so i leave my solution for others.

1. Get a secure message id with `RegisterWindowMessage()` (maybe paranoid, but the mechanism is completely trasparent for the targets..)
2. Get the thread id of the target window from its HWND with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`
3. Install a hook with `::SetWindowsHookEx` parametrized with `WH_CALLWNDPROC`
4. Inside the hook routine ignore all the msgs other than our special one.
   When that MSG is found, run the callback carried with wParam
5. Trigger the whole thing with `SendMessage` passing the special MSG id and the pointer of the routine that contains the code to be executed

Everything can be encapsulated in a function and used as invokeOnWndProc(HWND, lambda_Callback)

PROS: code runs in UI thread, completely transparent, synchronous behavior!
CONS: quite heavyweight..

Answer (score 1):

Replace the GetMessage call with a call to MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() API.  It's a lot of typing, but it should work...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx